# What is the time limit on requests that have them?

Tags: persona-q

Some requests have a time limit attached to them. But unlike regular persona games there is no date to be based on and I can't find a definite amount of time attached to any of them. So, what is the time limit on these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time limits do not appear to be specific. Those requests just must be finished before the completion of the current labyrinth.